# M2 Custom Extension 404 save error

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, extensions, adminform, save

I'm trying to write a fairly simple extension that can save data to an admin grid. I've been using the Magento CMS module as an example of this, I have my grid, I can click new and enter data, but when I click save I get a 404 on this page:

> /admin/smashing_testimonials/testimonials/save/

I'm struggling to work this out as everything else works

> routes.xml

```
<router id="admin">
     <route id="smashing_testimonials" frontName="smashing_testimonials">
          <module name="Smashing_Testimonials"/>
     </route>
</router>
```

I have a Save.php in this path

> /app/code/Smashing/Testimonials/Controller/Adminhtml/Testimonials/Save.php

Part of my ui_component file:

> /Smashing/Testimonials/view/adminhtml/ui_component/smashing_testimonials_form.xml

```
<dataSource name="smashing_testimonial_form_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="smashing_testimonials/testimonials/save"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Smashing\Testimonials\Model\Testimonial\DataProvider" name="smashing_testimonial_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
```

The "submitURL" is where Magento knows where to look for my save logic right? It certainly sends me to that admin url when I click save, so I presume this is correct?

I've run all the usual setup:upgrade, setup:static-content:deploy, cache:clean, etc.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Add your controller code

Comment: Hi Sohel, I have changed my controller file to the version suggested below by Sweety but still hitting a 404 error. If I am getting a 404 presumably Magento isn't even finding the relevant file? I will also add my ui_component file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a case sentivitivty thing.

I had to change

```
Controller/Adminhtml/Testimonials/Save.php
```

to

```
Controller/Adminhtml/testimonials/save.php
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your routes.xml file

```
<router id="admin">
        <route id="smashing_testimonials" frontName="smashing_testimonials">
            <module name="Smashing_Testimonials" before="Magento_Adminhtml" />
        </route>
    </router>
```

2. Change your controller file

```
<?php

namespace Smashing\Testimonials\Controller\Adminhtml\Testimonials;


class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}

?>
```

3. Create layout file (smashing_testimonials_testimonials_save.xml)

app\code\Smashing\Testimonials\view\adminhtml\layout\smashing_testimonials_testimonials_save.xml

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Smashing\Testimonials\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Index" name="testimonials_block_adminhtml_index_index"  template="Smashing_Testimonials::testimonials_index_index.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
```

4. Create testimonials_index_index.phtml file

app\code\Smashing\Testimonials\view\adminhtml\templates\testimonials_index_index.phtml

```
// your phtml file code
```

5. Run below command

```
1. bin/magento setup:di:compile
2. bin/magento c:f
3. chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

**Now you can successfully access your file.**

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but no luck, I have added extra info to my original post.